# How to create a hidden input field in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to create a hidden input field in a lightning component to pass a default value.

```
<lightning:input aura:id="quoteField" name="name" label="Name"
value="{!v.newQuote.Name}" required="true"/>
```

I want to replace this fiels by:

```
name = {!v.opportunity.Name} + " - New Quote"
```

Comment: Why do you want to have a hidden field in lightning?

Comment: I just want to set a default value to this field.

Comment: Why you need to have a hidden input field? you can put your logic of the default value in the Controller side

Comment: You could use [`lightning attributes`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm) to hold default value.

Comment: Ok. I will try this.

Comment: I thought there was an inoutHidden component??

Comment: Don't think that an inputHidden component exists? Don't find it.

The best way is to set the default value in the controller. I try to make it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are basically two ways to achieve this

### 1 - SLDS Styling

You could use [SLDS styling](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/) classes, `.slds-hide` or `.slds-hidden`, to hide your component from user and let it hold the value for later use.

Your input component would be hidden as

```
<lightning:input aura:id="quoteField" name="name" label="Name" value="{!v.newQuote.Name}" required="true" class="slds-hidden" />
```

**Note:** `.slds-hidden` will take up space on your UI even thought the component would be hidden, whereas, `.slds-hide` will not take up space on UI for the hidden component. So it upto you which style to use.

### 2 - Using attributes

> **Component**

```
<!-- attribute which will be set in JS controller -->
<aura:attribute type="String" name="hiddenAttrib" default="anyvalue" />
<!-- -->
<aura:attribute name="name" type="String" default="New Quote"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:input aura:id="quoteField" name="name" label="Name"
                 value="{!v.name}" required="true"/>
```

> **JS Controller**

You can then access your attribute in your JS controller and set it to your desired value or pass on to specific component or do some calculations/working on it.

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var hidden = component.get("v.hiddenAttrib");
        var quote = component.get("v.name");
        component.set("v.name", quote + ' - ' + hidden);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Mahmmod.

The first solution is very interesting because I don't want that the use can see the field. I just want to set a default value to this field/parameter.

Comment: @YesPapa : Please accept the answer if it helped, so others with similar issues may find the answer helpful as well.

Comment: @Mahmmod. In the first solution, how can set the default value.

Comment: You can create aura:attribute and assign it to the input component.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attribute solution:

```
<aura:attribute name="name" type="String" default="New Quote"/>
<lightning:input aura:id="quoteField" name="name" label="Name"
value="{!v.newQuote.Name}" required="true"/>
```

I'd like a controller solution - I can't see how to start but certainly the best solution because I don't want that the user can see the field with the default value.